# ¿Cómo inicializar una variable privada de una clase tipo Bean?

Tags: java, spring

¿Cuál es la forma correcta para inicializar, con algún valor, una variable privada de una clase tipo Bean?.

Estoy usando **Spring Framework 3.1.1**

En mi caso quiero inicializar con ciertos valores la variable palettes.

```
@Service
public class MyServicesImpl implements IMyServices {

    private Map<Integer, String> palettes;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible inicializar los valores de la variable, usando la anotación [@PostConstruct](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-nature)

```
@PostConstruct
void init(){
    palettes = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    palettes.put(1, "#610B21");
    palettes.put(2, "#088A4B");
    ...
}
```